# How to address the next iterator in a loop and insert an element at a same address?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, insert, iterator

1) I have got an error while I tried to access next iterator of the inner loop by using next(). I was wondering where this error comes from. To be specific I have a vector of lists and I want to check connection feasibility with the next element, that's what `feas[it2][(next(it2))]`  does.

2) After the if condition satisfies, I would like to insert an element, lets say 3, at the same address. If you could correct the insert function I will be so grateful.

To sum up, I want to know how can I have access to next element within the list?, and also how to insert a value at the same address?

Many thanks

```
vector<list<int>>temp;
for (const auto& it1 : temp)
{

    for (const auto& it2 : it1)
    {

        if (feas[it2][(next(it2))] == 1)
        {
            temp[it1].insert (it2,3);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `it2` is **not** an iterator.

Comment: can you help me to correct the question! cheers

Comment: I have already sorted out the problem, but I'm looking for an elegant way to do the above mentioned operations. I was wondering what is the most efficient way to develop the code.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to insert into a `vector` that you are iterating over.

EDIT: You can insert and delete elements from a 'vector' as you iterate over it **if** the vector does not resize itself.

The only option is to move over the `vector` with indexes.

Example:

```
vector<list<int>>temp;
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < temp[i].size; j++)
    {

        if (feas[i][j + 1)] == 1)
        {
            temp[i].insert(temp.begin()+j, 3);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The insert part should be edited as  'temp[i].insert(temp.begin()+j, 3);', but still it doesn't work. The point is I have already had such a case with vector of vectors but the same approach doesn't fit with vector of lists as it seems.

Comment: @IMI Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you are using a `vector<list<>>` as opposed to a `vector<vector<>>`?

Comment: I switched to 'vector<deque<int>>' for having less computation time in the main loops. I asked the question in the early stage since I am worried about the efficiency of the main loops. Just wondering would it be better if I use lambdas for above operations. Looking forward to hearing any idea in this regard. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If checking with the previous element can work for you :

```
int temp = -1;
for (const auto& it2 : it1)
{
    if (feas[temp][itr2] == 1)
    {
        temp[it1].insert (temp,3);
    }
    temp = it2;
}
```

than you might want to try something like that , as itr2 holds the values in the list